# Matlab: I/O Delay detection

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, delay

I have a continuous process with 3 inputs and 1 output. The 3 inputs are consecutive in time: Input 1 lags the output by 30 minutes, Input 2 by 15 etc.

My dataset below shows a startup for the system after a shutdown:

```
I1 I2 I3 Out
0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0
8 4 0 0
13 8 6 0
22 13 9 3.2
```

It can be seen how input1 started and everything else followed.

My question: in Matlab, what should I look for in order to determine such I/O delay for more complex datasets?

Comment: Captain Obvious to the rescue: you should look (in any language, not only MATLAB) for changes in the input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay a close look to xcorr

xcorr performs a cross-correlation between two vectors (typically time signals) and checks their conformity in dependence of a time shift between the signals. A constant I/O lag should appear as a local maximum value for the correlation coefficient.

Comment: That can only work though, if the inputs are actually correlated - which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Which approach is more promising to you?